# How can I chat with BlackBerry users?

Tags: applications, instant-messaging

Is there an app that lets me chat with BlackBerry users just by adding their PINs? Something that simulates that my Android phone belongs to the BlackBerry network?

I know there are multiplatform options like [WhatsApp](http://www.whatsapp.com/) but I am talking about an app that lets me chat with people who are using the native BlackBerry Messenger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.  RIM's PIN system and BBM are proprietary.  You can only communicate with a BlackBerry user via PIN messages or BBM if you have a BlackBerry.

<sub>Get a new Bold 9900 / 9930, they're great! Full disclosure: I work for RIM. This is not an official statement from RIM either, this is me speaking as a user in my off time at home. I honestly think the new Bold is the best BB yet.</sub>

Comment: Wasn't RIM working on making BBM multi-platform? I thought I read that somewhere.

Comment: @Chahk I haven't heard anything about that myself.